# How to read a dictionary tree

Tags: python, dictionary, tree

Let us assume to have the following tree structure:

```
a = [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 4), (6, 5), (7, 8), (8, 11), (9, 10), (10, 11), (11, 11)]
```

so we get with this code [Python - Generate a dictionary(tree) from a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34964878/python-generate-a-dictionarytree-from-a-list-of-tuples) the structure

```
[{'id': 2, 'Children': [{'id': 1}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 4, 'Children': [{'id': 5, 'Children': [{'id': 6}]}]}]}, {'id': 11, 'Children': [{'id': 8, 'Children': [{'id': 7}]}, {'id': 10, 'Children': [{'id': 9}]}]}]
```

my question: how can I take all children of a special node of this dictionary?
for example: all the children of 11 are: (7, 8, 9, 10)
what to do?

Comment: collect that data in code where it is tree created

Comment: Is there no other possibility? assume there is only the output above...

Comment: it is but easier is to do this like i said earlier

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator to find the desired children of a node. First, for easier lookup later, use recursion to restructure the tree:

```
data = [{'id': 2, 'Children': [{'id': 1}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 4, 'Children': [{'id': 5, 'Children': [{'id': 6}]}]}]}, {'id': 11, 'Children': [{'id': 8, 'Children': [{'id': 7}]}, {'id': 10, 'Children': [{'id': 9}]}]}]
def rebuild(d):
  return {i['id']:None if 'Children' not in i else rebuild(i['Children']) for i in d}

result = rebuild(data)
```

Now, apply a recursive generator function:

```
def get_children(d):
  for a, b in d.items():
    yield a
    if isinstance(b, dict):
       yield from get_children(b)

print(sorted(get_children(result[11])))
```

Output:

```
[7, 8, 9, 10]
```